# What would happen if I changed permissions of 'Program Files (x86)' folder on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

1. What if I went ahead and added "Everyone" in 'Program Files (x86)'s permissions tab and gave 'Everyone' full access?
2. and if I deleted every other permission than 'Everyone'?

Comment: What problem are you attempting to resolve by doing this exactly?

Comment: why should it matter? @Ramhound

Comment: Because changing the permissions on Program Files will break any application contained within the WindowsApps directory. I want to be able to solve your problem without breaking your entire install

Comment: I don't really have a problem, I was just curious. Thanks for the help and the concern.

Answer (score 2):

In the normal course of events this is impossible, but there exist hacks
that could enable it.

After you succeed, Windows will become unusable.
You will need to reinstall Windows from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

> What if I went ahead and added "Everyone" in 'Program Files (x86)'s
> permissions tab and gave 'Everyone' full access?
>
> and if I deleted every other permission than 'Everyone'?

This folder is owned by "All Application Packages" and the security permissions cannot natively be changed (I just tried on a test machine).

In the regular use of a computer, there has not been a need to change these permissions, so I suggest you do not try this.

If you mess up your computer, it will need a major repair. Messed up registries normally mean reinstalling Windows.